# java array of booleans all set to the same value

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

In java, is it possible to make an `Array` of `booleans` that when any `boolean` is set to a specified value,(example, false) all are set to the same value. (if ones value is false, all values will be set to false.)

I will be having a loop that keeps adding more to the `Array`, so individual setting is not an option.

Any help is appreciated. I am not going to post code.

Comment: Why do you want an array when they all have the same value?

Comment: "*any help is appreciated. i am not going to post code.*"

Comment: I want them to only have the same value if one is set to a certain value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method that fills an array of booleans with the selected value, this might be what you are after:

[`Arrays.fill(boolean[] a, boolean val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29)

*Assigns the specified boolean value to each element of the specified array of booleans.*

Answer (score 1):

Implement a method yourself which is used when setting values of the array. The method can then ensure the constraints you have thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in that does this, but you could easily just implement such an array yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Think about another solution: implement a mutable boolean class and point all the variables that you need to that mutable boolean. When you'll change the value of one of them, all the values will be changed. I could post some code, but I'm not going to :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of booleans such that all values would change to true or false if one of the booleans in the array has its value changed to true or false.

Given the ambiguity of the question, I am not sure how the booleans are being changed, but assuming you have a place in the code that sets them. You could implement something like this psuedocode:

```
//boolean x changed to true(or false)
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    //set each value of the booleans to the same value as boolean x
```

Hope this helps.